# Batch file: store output function call in var

Tags: batch-file, variables, call

This doesn't seem to be that hard, however, can't seem to get the output of a function call stuffed into a variable.

```
SET info=
call git log -6
REM echo %info%
echo { "timestamp": "%time% %date%", "info": "%info%" } >> ".\src\assets\build-info.json"
```

Some or a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to have your command output a more [easily parseable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---formatltformatgt) output, and send it to a file.

You could then use [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to read a the file line by line (even tokenize the lines) into a variable, then write the variable to a file.

for example:

```
git log --format="%aI | %an | %s" > git.log
(for /f "delims=| tokens=1-3" %a in (git.log) do @echo {"timestamp":"%a", "info":"%c"}) > git.log.json
```

Comment: I actually had a solution a bit like (in mind) this only not as elegant. I will go ahead with your approach, grazie.